# Reescritura de urls con PHP .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Tengo una web multilenguaje y quisiera que cuando un usuario busque `www.pagina.com/algo` y si ese `/algo` existe, que se redireccionara a la de su lenguaje `www.pagina.com/es/algo` y asi con todos, como `www.pagina.com/algo/subdirectorio` a `www.pagina.com/es/algo/subdirectorio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría desde el propio lenguaje de programación directamente.

Entiendo que el usuario seleccionará en algún momento el idioma que desea por lo que en ese momento lo que yo haría sería guardar el idioma seleccionado en una cookie, localstorage, o si el usuario está registrado, en un campo de la base de datos.

Entonces al entrar el usuario a la web utilizaría un condicional de ésta manera.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["language"])){
  header("Location: /www.mipagina.com/" . $_COOKIE["language"]);
}
```

Aquí lo primero que he hecho es preguntarle al programa si está establecida la cookie llamada language y si es afirmativo redirecciono la página a la del lenguaje que contiene la cookie.

Para ello te recomiendo que en la cookie guardes el lenguaje con la misma nomenclatura que utilizas en la url, por ejemplo si para el idioma español utilizas [www.mipagina.com/es](http://www.mipagina.com/es) entonces guarda el lenguaje de la cookie o el campo de la base de datos como "es". Si para el idioma inglés utilizas [www.mipagina.com/en](http://www.mipagina.com/en) entonces lo guardas como "en", etc.

Y si en vez de cookies utilizas para los usuario registrados una base de datos, podrías hacerlo añadiendo un campo language a la tabla usuarios de la base de datos y luego sigues el mismo procedimiento utilizando un condicional pero en este caso haciendo una consulta a la base de datos, aunque yo lo haría mediante cookies o similar para darle la misma posibilidad a todos los usuarios estén registrados o no.

Answer (score 1):

buen dia

Podes hacer un condicional utilizando switch

```
$url = $_GET['url']
switch ($url) {
case "https://www.pagina.com/algo/subdirectorio":
    header('Location: www.pagina.com/es/algo/subdirectorio');
    break;
 }
```

y así sucesivamente

Lo que estoy planteando es hacer un script (función) que se encargue de hacer las redirecciones que necesitas y utilizarla en la sección de código que necesites.
En el ejemplo que di arriba lo que hago es obtener la url por get, se la paso al switch y doy un caso en particular, si la url es X, entonces se va a redireccionar a otra.

No es muy recomendable hacerlo utilizando htaccess ya que puede generar confuciones en tu web.

Espero que mi respuesta sea de utilidad, saludos.